# jQuery attaching a file and detecting empty input field

Tags: jquery, events

### HTML

```
<input type="file" style="display: none" id="uploadme" /> <br />
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="Upload Stuff!" />
```

### jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        $('#uploadme').click();

        if( $("#uploadme").val()=='') {
            alert("empty");
        }
    });
});
```

When the user click the "Upload Stuff!" button, the windows shows the files to be uploaded. If the user clicks on the cancel button of the opened window, then the input field is empty otherwise the hidden input field contains the selected file.
I was trying to detect whether the hidden input field is empty or not. If the input field is empty, that is, user cancel and does not want to attach anything, then I have to do something. Similarly, if the user selects some files, then I have to do something else.

How can I detect that in above code to find whether the input field (id="uploadme") is empty or not empty?

Here is the running code in jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeewanaryal/RuqVS/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code works...

Comment: I think you answered your own question with your if statement duder :)

Comment: no it does not work. You can try in that jsfiddle link. click on the "Upload Stuff!" button and try to attach some file from your computer and click "Open". When you attach/upload some file, then the input field is NOT EMPTY but still the alert message pops up :(

Comment: I have to make it like, if some file is chosen then the alert message should not be popped up.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this by checking the value of $('#uploadme').files.length . If it's 0, then there's no files selected, meaning the input field is empty.

```
if( $("#uploadme").files.length == 0) {
    alert("empty");
}
```